# Reordering ADO Recordset columns

Tags: delphi, ado, recordset

I have a recordset with columns 
e.j

```
ID_PEOPLE

NAME

AGE
```

And I need to reorder this columns to

```
ID_PEOPLE

AGE

NAME
```

This recordset is used to fill an Excel spreadsheet and need to change the recordset column order because reordering in Excel is to slow.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your Table/Query, select Field Editor.

If there are not fields, press CTRL+F.

Drag by mouse fields changing order as you want.

Or, if you have a Query, you may change select field order: select Field2, Field1 from Table.

Or you may physicaly redesign field order in your table/view/procedure.

Comment: I Cant access the query. My method gets the recordset as a param

Comment: @AgustinSeifert, When you do for example: RecordSet.Open(SelectString, DSN, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdUnspecified); put in SelectString fields in required order: select FieldB, FieldA from Table

Comment: I cant... for example my procedure is:
procedure FillExcel(rs: _recordset)
begin
  // do something here to reorder
  rsToExcel(rs);
end;

Comment: init rs variable properly before calling FillExcel